# Picking a random file from a random folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a series of folders online, which have a series of files in each.
I want to be able to get a random file.

I can only access these files by URL.

Here is an example of the folder structure:

Folder 0:  000000
Folder 1:  001000
Folder 2:  002000
Folder 99: 099000

It ends at 99 so that's 100 folders

Inside each folder are files, so for folder 003000:

File 0:   003000
File 1:   003001
File 99:  003999

So that is 1000 files per folder.

I managed to work out how to get a random folder in this range and get the string for it to be able to add into the URL string, but I am now trying to get the random file within that folder. What would be a good way to do this?

```
var randomFolderNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
var randomNumberString;
var selectedFolderString;
var selectedFile;
console.log("rand:" + randomFolderNumber)
if (randomFolderNumber < 10) {
    randomNumberString = randomFolderNumber.toString() + "0";
    selectedFolderString = "00" + randomNumberString + "00";
} else {
    randomNumberString = randomFolderNumber.toString()
    selectedFolderString = "0" + randomNumberString + "000";
}

console.log(selectedFolder)

//selectedFile = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + selectedFolderString)
```

Comment: 1 line, `String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999)).padStart(6, '0'))`

Comment: Awesome!, I also need the folder number itself, should I just append the way I get it to the file, or is there a faster way?

Comment: np `var folder = num.substr(0, 3)`

Comment: thanks! very efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your number is in a range between 0 and 99999 with 0 left padding, you can generate the number in one shot:

```
const number = String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 99999)).padStart(6, '0'))
```

Then you can split it, if you need the parts:

```
const folder = number.substr(0, 3)
const file = number.substr(3)
```